# org.mule.api.MessagingException: com.mulesoft.weave.reader.ByteArraySeekableStream cannot be cast to oracle.sql.CLOB

Tags: mule

Am facing this exception when am calling stored procedure with "clob" as data type  for inserting xml data into database using mulesoft,its showing exception on oracle .
this is my config file

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc"
    xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-sfdc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <flow name="opp_to_sales_orderFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/opportunity" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" query="SELECT Id, Product_Name__c,  Account.name  FROM Opportunity " doc:name="Salesforce"/>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
---

  list: { (payload map {
      linked-hash-map : {
      name:$.Account.Name,
      id: $.Id,
      Product_name: $.Product_Name__c

   }
  })
   }
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>

        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[call xxnew_order_create.xxenv_order_creation8(
                                                :p_mule_input,
                                                :x_order_cursor
                                                :x_error_code,                                                                      :x_error_message,
                                                :x_sales_order
                                                )]]></db:parameterized-query>
            <db:in-param name="p_mule_input" type="LONGVARCHAR" value="#[message.payload]"/>
            <db:out-param name="x_order_cursor" type="CURSOR"/>
            <db:out-param name="x_sales_order" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="x_error_code" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <db:out-param name="x_error_message" type="VARCHAR"/>
        </db:stored-procedure>


        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>

        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Exception Handling ">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="StartLog"/>
            <set-payload value="{ &quot;errorMessage&quot; : &quot;#[exception.message]&quot;, &quot;exception&quot;:&quot;#[exception.getDetailedMessage()]&quot; }" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/html" doc:name="Catch Exception"/>
            <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="400" doc:name="http.status"/>
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="EndLog"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>

    </flow>

</mule>
```

---

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comma was missing in procedure parameters now its working fine thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Please paste your config file it is due to type casting before passing as clob you need data is in string format.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use a groovy component and add the code like below.

```
clobTest = (java.sql.Clob)payload.your_field bodyText = clobTest.getCharacterStream() targetString = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(bodyText) payload.PAYLOADHEADERS=targetString return payload
```